# How can lua help class or package authors?

Tags: luatex, package-writing, documentclass-writing, lua

I am maintaining a rather simple class for internal company use for myself and some collegues. Mostly simple stuff like including the logo, setting the paper formats, adjust the colors, set headers and the document to different languages, ... - you get the idea.

In addition load all the packages we can agree on and include usefull macros. Nothing to fancy here.

TeX / LaTeX programming capabilities allway puzzles me and I always have huge issues figuring out the correct syntax and am constantly shooting myself in the foot.

Can lua help here provide the capabilities of a more "modern" scripting language?

So instead of using something like:

```
[...]
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\DeclareStringOption{language}

\ifthenelse{\equal{\myclassname@language}{deutsch}}
{
  \PassOptionsToClass{ngerman}{scrartcl}
  \PassOptionsToPackage{ngerman}{varioref}
  [more language specific loading]
}
{
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\myclassname@language}{english}}
  {
    \PassOptionsToClass{english}{scrartcl}
    \PassOptionsToPackage{english}{varioref}
[...]
  }
  {
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\myclassname@language}{portuges}}
    {
      \PassOptionsToClass{portuges}{scrartcl}
      \PassOptionsToPackage{portuges}{varioref}
[...]
    }
    {
[...]
  }
}
```

I just would get a string variable passed from the .tex file to the .cls file:

```
if (\myclassname@language == "deutsch") then
 function_deutsch(foo)
elseif (\myclassname@language == "english") then
  function_english(bar)
elseif (\myclassname@language == "portuges") then
 [...]
end
```

Compatibility to latex / pdflatex / xetex ... is not an issue and not requested

EDIT:
Solution based on lua functions not further pursued. Rewrite on basis of expl3 / latex3 e.g. is favoured ([as asked here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544374/passing-options-to-a-class-and-evaluate-using-latex3-interfaces)):

Comment: I don't think that lua would make it easier, you would have to handle two programming languages and also understand how tex and lua communicate. If you want to be a bit more modern then better use expl3. Generally all your ifthenelse are too complicated. Define `\myclass@settings@german` and `\myclass@settings@english` etc and then call `\csname myclass@settings@\myclassname@language\endcsname` to activate the right language settings.

Comment: [expl3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3) is announced as wrapper for _experimental_ features of LaTeX3 which describes itself as [latex3](https://www.latex-project.org/latex3/) _a long-term research project_.

So an wrapper of experminental functions of a research project. Ist this something somebody should use for production?

Comment: LaTeX's kernel uses expl3. But concerning Lua: In ConTeXt you can properly mix and match Lua and TeX (including using only one of the languages for document design). But in LaTeX, Lua is restricting you to one engine and wrt to programming expl3 is more TeXy and natural there.

Comment: Expl3 is used in lots if package and since this year it has been included in the latex format, you don't need a package to use it. It is now an official part of latex

Comment: Ok - so expl3 or at least the functionality started there and around the latex3 project seems to be the way to go. I will need to check this out.